# Compare 2 similar columns from differernt tables to produce 1 output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB. TableA and TableB has the column'address' but the values are similar. TableA would have '3 Hope Road' and TableB would have 'Hope Road.'TableB would also have the column 'AccountNumber.' Is there a way I can compare the similarity of both'address' columns and if they are similar,produce one output giving the columns 'address' and 'AccountNumber'?

Comment: How can you possibly make an assumption like that?  So what happens when you hit Main St. from Springfield, IL and Main St. from Springfield, MA?  You're going to associate 5 Main St. with which one? Address matching requires a lot more than just your street name.

Comment: You can join both tables and use the 'Like' operator to compare the addresses. More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator to compare strings which are 'similar':

```
SELECT B.address, B.accountNumber FROM tableA as A inner join tableB as B 
ON B.address like concat('%', A.address)
```